# Return only styles attribute inside a table, tr and td tag

Tags: html, regex

I want to get only the attribute style inside a table, tr and td.

The following regex code return all the variations that I can have in my HTML elements:

```
((style=")([a-zA-Z0-9:;\.\s\(\)\-\,]*)(")|(style=)([a-zA-Z0-9:;\.\s\(\)\-\,]*)( )|(style=)([a-zA-Z0-9:;\.\s\(\)\-\,]*))
```

It returns all the styles for all the tags, and I want to restrict only to the tags **tabe, tr and td**

Online example:
https://regexr.com/69q7k

Screenshot that I want:
[image]

Comment: Can't you do it via JS? That would be simpler. Imagine you have some HTML like `<span data-custom="<td style>" style="background: rgba(0,0, 10, .2);">`

Comment: @Justinas I can't use it via JS

Comment: If it always like this example, then you can try `<(?:table|tr|td) ((style=")....`

Comment: @Justinas I already tried that, but it will select the <table for example

Comment: Use `/\b(?<=<t(?:able|[rd])\s*)style=(?:"[^"]*"|\S*)/gi`. In PHP/Onigmo/Boost: `<t(?:able|[rd])\s*\Kstyle=(?:"[^"]*"|\S*)`. Only for the samples above, where the `style` attribute comes right after tag name. You may get to the attribute by adding `[^>]*` instead of `\s*`. E.g. `<t(?:able|[rd])\b[^>]*\Kstyle=(?:"[^"]*"|\S*)`, see [this demo](https://regexr.com/69qhc).